# Matthews account of Jesus' conception appears from the perspective of Joseph. It is often conflated with Lukes version. Are the sources the same?

Tags: matthew, luke, synoptic-problem

It is tempting to counter Mary and the Holy Spirit’s silence in the Matthean account of Jesus' conception with Luke’s poetic detailing through conflation of materials from two gospels.   However some scholars argue the versions developed independently of each other (Bellinzoni, 2016, 325; Foxwell and Mann 1971,6). For instance, Bellinzoni (Arthur J. (2016). The New Testament: An Introductiion to Biblical Scholarship. Eugene, OR: Wipf & Stock.)undertakes a detailed comparison of the birth stories in Matthew and Luke concluding it “reveals their independent character and, hence, the fact that they used different sources.”

This is not a separate question, but by way of emphasising serious issues at stake.  If Matthews version is stand alone,  given the age of betrothal of the times was 13 - there are huge power imbalances occuring in this scene.   Mary's silence in Matthews version comes with all sorts of issues.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Comment: Re Vote to Close, this is fundamentally a question about the Synoptic Problem, which is in scope for the site. I have tagged the question accordingly.

Comment: The supposed 'betrothal of the times' is untrue. And also irrelevant. There is no _evidence_ in the text of Mary's age at betrothal. This question appears to be a matter of various opinions, rather than an hermeneutic analysis of the text itself.

Answer (score 1):

This depends in part upon one's solution to the [Synoptic Problem](https://youtu.be/ySIIZWu8A6w) (disclaimer--the link is to my own work on the subject). I'll offer an answer from the perspective of each of the 3 most common solutions to the Synoptic Problem and then some general comments.

**Two-Gospel Hypothesis**

This theory holds that Matthew was written first, and was used as a source by Luke. Mark subsequently utilized both Matthew & Luke as sources. In this case, Luke was very familiar with Matthew's account, but since most of his Nativity account is not found in Matthew, Luke apparently had other sources as well.

**Two-Source Hypothesis**

This theory holds that Mark was written first, and that Mark and another, non-extant document commonly referred to as Q, were independently used as sources by Matthew & Luke. In this case, Luke's account is independent of Matthew.

**Farrer Hypothesis**

This theory holds that Mark was written first, then Matthew who used Mark as a source, and then Luke who used both Mark & Matthew as sources. In this case, Luke was very familiar with Matthew's account, but since most of his Nativity account is not found in Matthew, Luke apparently had other sources as well.

**General Comments**

[My own work](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGACqQS4ut5iFeKqqvQPK_dzMnjF7NBhw) on the Synoptic Problem leads me to 2 conclusions that are relevant to this question:

1. Luke was familiar with Matthew's Gospel
2. Luke had access to other information as well, and was thus not solely reliant upon Matthew.

For those who accept that Luke-Acts is a generally reliable historical work (I do--see previous link), it is evident that under any solution to the Synoptic Problem, Luke had access to a source within Jesus' immediate family. The very personal details from Mary in Luke's account (such as Luke 1:28-56) suggest to some the possibility that Luke may have interviewed Mary and obtained this information from her directly. Matthew's account could more easily be explained as the abbreviated version derived from one of Jesus' brothers. (Acts indicates that the apostles and James the Lord's brother were well-acquainted).

Re power imbalance--in first century Jewish culture women generally did not have a say in whom they married. Citing an account (or a genealogy) from the husband's perspective would not be culturally unusual. Neither nativity account tells us Mary's age nor how long she had been betrothed to Joseph when the annunciation occurred.

Comment: Would the user who downvoted all of my recent posts care to offer some constructive feedback?

Comment: I upvoted your post. I also look forward to the critique of those who downvoted your post.